# como puedo crear una expresión regular para validar citas bíblicas?

Tags: regex

Estoy intentando crear una expresión regular para validar citas biblicas como estas:

```
 1 de tesalonicenses 4:20-40
 mateo 8:34
 marcos 6:2-40
 mateo 7
```

Pero que me valide negativo citas como estas:

```
mateo 345:0
mateo 
1 tesalonicenses 7:20
mateo 8:3-567
```

yo he creado esta expresión:

```
(?!\s)([1-3]{1} de )?([a-z]{3,15} [0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2})(-[0-9]{1,2}){0,1}
```

pero no marca falso este tipo de citas:

```
1 tesalonicenses 7:20
1 mateo 6:20-348
```

gracias de antemano por su ayuda.

Les comparto esta pagina donde pruebo las expresiones regulares https://regexr.com/

Comment: Deberías agregar a tu pregunta lo que has intentado hacer.

Comment: ¿Estás usando Flex? En es caso debes agregar otra regla en la que utilices el . (esto indica que todo lo que no aplique en reglas anteriores aplicara en esta regla) y en esa regla agregas el mensaje de error. A demás considero que como lo que buscas son verificar 2 palabras en este caso deberías utilizar un analizador sintáctico con un analizador léxico

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Respondo a mi propia pregunta ya que no he encontrado una respuesta acertada:

Mi solución un poco fea pero funcional para validar el formato de citas bíblicas:

```
/^[0-9] de [a-zA-Z]{3,14} [0-9]{1,2}$|^[0-9] de [a-zA-Z]{3,14} [0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}$|^[0-9] de [a-zA-Z]{3,14} [0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}$|^[a-zA-Z]{3,14} [0-9]{1,2}$|^[a-zA-Z]{3,14} [0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}$|^[a-zA-Z]{3,14} [0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}$/
```

Si alguien puede y quiere simplificarla para que se vea elegante y profesional estaría muy bien. Sino pues ojala ayude a alguien mi solución.